# iOS 8 Custom keyboard autolayout issues

Tags: xcode, keyboard, autolayout

I just finished laying out all my buttons for a custom keyboard (xib file) and when I finished adding all the constraints, I didn't have any autolayout issues but when I try to run it either on the simulator or on my 5S, the view isn't the correct size it looks like all of the items in the view sized correctly but the view did not. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is what it's supposed to look like:

[image: IB]

Here is what it looks like live:

[image]

And in the preview in IB:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors in the debug console when you run it? (Does that work when debugging custom keyboards?)

Comment: No I don't get warnings or anything (I don't think that works with custom keyboards..yet). It works perfectly except that the view is completely off so I can't see most of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to set the frame of the keyboard view equal to the frame of it's superview

```
self.keyboardView.frame = self.view.frame;
```

simple mistake

Comment: Hi, Can you point out where exactly you need to set this frame, whats `keyboardView` ?

Comment: keyboard view is the view that I loaded from my xib file. Directly before you add your custom view (in my case keyboard view), it needs to know what size the containing view is. So I set the custom view's frame equal to the view.frame (it's containing view). Then just add it using `[self.view addSubview: customView];`